# Symfony 2.8: $form->getData() in controller for updating existed Entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have two actions in my controller `newAction`, `editAction`. I use the Symfony form, so in the `newAction` I use next code:

```
$entity = $form->getData();
$this->em->persist($entity);
$this->em->flush();
```

for creating a new row in the database.

So how can I use another form in the `editAction` for updating existed entity? BTW in my edit form, some additional fields are added and some fields from the first form are removed.

```
$entity = $repo->find($id);
$entity = $form->getData();
$this->em->persist($entity);
$this->em->flush();
```

Ofc this code tries to create a new one. I have a big form and I'm not sure it's a good idea to use `$entity->setField($form->getField());`

Comment: Why you don't use form type ? but you can $entity->setXXX($form->get('fild_name')->getData();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was I forgot to add my entity during creating the form

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), **$myEntity**);
```

So now everything works fine